# How to remove iframe style of "site-preview" in WordPress theme Customizer Settings?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

When I clicked on any blog post from theme customizer setting then iframe title site-preview is opening with 150px of height.
Again when I disabled its style from inspect element then it is working nicely.

This was not the case 2 days back. It was working absolutely fine.

Comment: so, what changed in the last two days? surely you must've done something. websites don't spontaneously change themselves

Comment: I just changed css codes in additional CSS section, added some plugins. I don't think that the themes get changed by this. Also I tried removing those to check whether this problem happened with that.

Comment: Anyway can I restore my complete backup without any setting? I have already maintained everyday backup with updraft.

Comment: If you have backups then yes, you can revert back to what you had two days ago.

Comment: `I just changed css codes` - that's probably the source of the change then

Comment: I have installed theme manually and just uploaded media files and database.

I thought it will work but still not worked.

Please help me.